# Align Menu Strip in Center of a parent container control of Winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a C# winform application where i have added a menustrip control inside a panel control. My problem is that the menus started from left side automatically. I need to display the menus in center position of the panel container control. How can i display the menu in center position ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Non-standard UI like this is never a good idea.  But you can have it, just set the Dock property to None and you can put it anywhere you like.  Or change the first menu item's Padding property, give it a big Left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a 3 column tablelayoutpanel, with the 2 outside columns set to Percentage 50%  and the middle column set to autosize and drop the menustrip inside the middle column and dock it, then the middle column will autosize as you add menu items and no coding required.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click the little arrow  top right on menu strip and click embed in toolstrip container and you can place it everywhere you want if panels size or location is changing in runtime you can set menustrip's location programaticaly